# Реализация ввода десятичных цифр

Tags: c#, asp.net

Всем доброго!
Народ помогите новичку никак не могу решить вопрос вводы десятичных цифр. Как это делать правильно.

Есть модель:

```
public decimal Proba1 { get; set; }
```

стандартная форма ввода не дает вводить десятичные знаки не через " , " не через " . ".

```
<input asp-for="Proba1" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть проблемы заключалась в следующем: `ASP NET Core` стало по умолчанию использовать `JqueryValidation`. И вот тут произошла накладка так как база ждала разделитель в виде "`,`". А `jQuery` не пропускал и ждал точку. В результате нельзя было вообще ввести дробное число.
В документации на `ASP NET Core` я нашел предупреждение об этом. Еще не до конца разобрался как можно правильно и полноценно включить Локализацию, по этому пошел наверно не по самому верному пути просто в самом файле `JqueryValidation.js` заменил разделитель.

```
// http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/
    number: function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || /^(?:-?\d+|-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\,\d+)?$/.test( value );
    },
```

Он вот в этом блоке

```
(?:\,\d+)
```

Решение я взял вот здесь [jQuery validate and the comma decimal separator](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2011/03/02/jquery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator). Но пока так и не смог найти как правильно и полно сделать локализацию `JqueryValidation`.

Comment: Какая у Вас своеобразная проблема...не такая уж она и детская.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо указать тип элемента `input`, для этого добавьте в него следующее свойство - `type="number"` и `step="any"`, тогда Ваш элемент будет числовым. Вот так:

```
<input asp-for="Proba1" class="form-control" type="number" step="any"/>
```

Браузеры, которые поддерживают `<input type="number">` будут отправлять `.` в качестве десятичного разделителя. Шаг можно установить и свой, к примеру `step="0.01"`.

Для того, чтобы браузеры корректно отрабатывали знак разделителя можно использовать `<input type="text">`, но в таком случае Вам придется использовать `JavaScript` библиотеки или `JQuery`, для того, чтобы контролировать введенные символы с клавиатуры.

Также можно воспользоваться аттрибутом `asp-format`. Ознакомиться можно тут [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). Тогда отображение числового значения с 4 знаками после запятой будет выглядеть так:

```
<input asp-for="Proba1" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:N4}"/>
```